# What is the best IDE to develop websites?

Tags: ide

I'm at the begging of my web development career and at the moment I use Atom to develop Websites. I really like the UI and big choice of shortcuts and command palette.

My question is, are the most powerful IDE's the same and its only a matter of taste to choose one or the other or is there some out there that have amazing features that are very helpful and other don't. If so, please come with arguments/examples. Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for a software are off-topic here. You can ask for recommendations at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: VS code is better